# Match keywords in large text file but ignore contents and new line between the keywords

Tags: php, regex

I need to search through a file for occurrence of certain keywords that have some texts in between them but these texts aren't so important in the process and they are dynamically created so I won't know before hand what they are but I need to use the keywords to search through the file while ignoring any other text in between them.

I tried something like this

```
$string = "Jason loves cookies, he plays soccer and is a fun guy. He wakes up at 9:14AM everyday";
$match = "Jason\s+(.*)\s+soccer\s+(.*)everyday";

preg_match('/'.$match.'/', $string);
```

but it doesn't match.

Any pointer in the right direction on how to achieve this is greatly appreciated. If possible with an example will be even more appreciated.

**EDIT**

The above matches but here is a [sample of what I am actually doing](https://3v4l.org/UuATA)

Comment: It [matches](https://3v4l.org/o2KhQ).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I didn't want to add the exact texts I am matching because of confidentiality but [check out a sample here](https://3v4l.org/LhPWd)

Comment: There is no match, that's all. There is no `NUMBER:3495` in your input.

Comment: Its actually `NUMBER:6647` and its there. When I remove the other parameters and search using only `NUMBER:6647` placeholder, it works but putting them back doesn't.

Comment: There is no `3495` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be fine with *strpos*.
It works like:

```
strpos($string, 'wordneeded');
```

But what you want as an output?